# How do I consume Linked API v2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have my app in LinkedIn with all four default application permissions ticked. I am able to consume API v1 perfectly. When I authenticate with oAuth 2.0, my authentication is successful and I get auth2_token but I am not able to call the below endpoint.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

> Header: X-Restli-Protocol-Version : 2.0.0   Authorization : Bearer (
>   auth2_token )

I get the error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
    "status": 403
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get access to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` either but you can use the  following URL sample to retrieve the data you need:

GET `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json`

The available fields can be found here: [LinkedIn basic profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Comment: I have tried consuming this url but it returns http status code 401, message: Unknown authentication scheme. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You gonna need to add an [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) with a [Bearer token](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes) when calling it. In order to get this token you need to complete the authentication through [LinkedIn Oauth2 process](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2).

Comment: I can't understand what you said or the whole process, can you suggest me a tutorial/blog for me to understand the process. Thank you in advance

Comment: The tutorial I followed was this one: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2. Please let me know if you still facing issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

To access https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me, you need to have access to v2 API.
As of 14th of Jannuary or Linkedin Applications will automatically have access to v2 API.
As of March, 1st, Linkedin is going to deprecate its v1 API, so the call https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json will no longer work.